# exception could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql

when i run my project sometimes message appear which like
"exception could not create connection to database server"
I'm using net beans and MySQL and i added MySQL_connector jar file to library

```
import AnswerAnalysis.CheckConstraint;
import AnswerAnalysis.ConstStatus;
import RetriveFromDataBase.Retirving_from_skills;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import AnswerAnalysis.ValueFeature;
```

import AnswerAnalysis.StudentAnswerElement;

Comment: Does `sometimes` mean the same code which uses DB connection executes successfully or throws this exception at random periods of time?

Comment: That's missing the part where you try and connect. This just boilerplate that has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If your code sometimes work and sometimes don't, without changes (ie. using the same jar/compiled class), so probably you have network problems.

Does MySQL is a available to other people? It could be misconfigured and it may be able to serve many concurrent sessions.